# How can I keep the value of `this` when I go inside a function?

Tags: javascript, scope

How can I keep the value of `this` when I go inside a function I lost the previous value of `this`

For example in this case how can I got the access to the `testFunction`.

```
admin = function()
{
    this.testFunction = function()
    {
    alert('hello');
    }

    this.test2Function = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            success: function()
            {
                 this.testFunction();
                 // here I got an error undefined 
            }
        });
     }
}
```

I've tried to keep the value of this on a self var like this

```
this.self = this;
```

but not work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
admin = function()
{
    var top = this;
    this.testFunction = function()
    {
    alert('hello');
    }

    this.test2Function = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            success: function()
            {
                 top.testFunction();   // should work :)
            }
        });
     }
}
```

All local variables defined in a function, propagate (could be accessed) through WHOLE function, including all functions defined in that function.

So `var top = this;` will carry it's value through all inner functions and objects declared inside of `admin`.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). The idomatic way of doing this in JavaScript is:

```
function foo(){
   //Store this in outer scoped variable.
   // It will be available to anything within this scope
   var that = this;

   innerCall(function(){
      that.doSomething();
   });
}
```

Comment: I like that you stripped out most of the syntactic noise.

Answer (score 1):

there are multiple ways it upto you and the big picture that which one suits

```
admin = function()
{
    this.testFunction = function()
    {
    alert('hello');
    }

    this.test2Function = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            success: this.testFunction
        });
     }
}
```

or

```
admin = function()
{
    var testFunction = function()
    {
    alert('hello');
    }

    this.test2Function = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            success: testFunction 
        });
     }
}
```

or

admin = function()
    {
        this.testFunction = function()
        {
        alert('hello');
        }

```
    var testFucntion = this.testFunction;

    this.test2Function = function()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            success: function(){ testFucntion(); } 
        });
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All the answers are correct, just for the record, by referring the [google style guide](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml#this):

> Because this is so easy to get wrong, limit its use to those places
>   where it is required:
>             in constructors
>             in methods of objects (including in the creation of closures)

IMO, the best approach is [Josh's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11354432/231917).

Answer (score 0):

Another potentially effective approach which would avoid handling `this` would be making the callbacks parameters:

```
admin = function()
{
    this.testFunction = function()
    {
        alert('hello');
    }

    this.test2Function = function(successCallback)
    {
        $.ajax({
            url:'',
            success: function()
            {
                 if(typeof(successCallback) === 'function') {
                     successCallback(); 
                 }
            }
        });
     }
}

//usage:
admin.test2Function(admin.testFunction);
```